# binomial distribution - colors

Tags: probability

In a package of M&Ms there are 20 pieces. The pieces come in 6 different colors: red, blue, green, yellow, orange and brown.  Assuming that the M&M colors occur with equal probability, what is the probability of getting 5 red M&Ms in a package.

Solution:

Would I be doing:

$$\dfrac{20!}{15!\cdot 5!}  \cdot  \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^5   \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{15}  = 0.1294$$

Thx.

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: exactly five or five or more?

Comment: Exactly 5.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. If you have a probability $p$ of success (getting a red M&M), and probability $q = 1 - p$ of failure (getting a blue or green or yellow or orange or brown M&M), then the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes in $n$ random trials (a package of $n$ randomly picked M&Ms) is
$${\large ^nC_k}\, p^k q^{n - k}$$

In this case, that's ${\large ^{20}C_5}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^5\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{15}$, as you've calculated.

Answer (score 0):

That is assuming the M&M's are ordered inside the bag, which doesn't make a lot of sense, if we don't care about the order within the bag:

Total number of packages can be obtained using stars and bars. We get $\binom{25}{5}$.Since we have to divide the $20$ sweets into $6$ colors.

There are $\binom{19}{4}$ bags containing exactly $5$ red M&M's.

There are $\binom{20}{5}$ bags containing at least $5$ red M&M's. So the probabilites for having exactly $5$ reds or at least $5$ reds are $7\%$ and $29\%$ respectively

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{npq}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Large e}^{-\dfrac{(k-np)^2}{2npq}}$$

In addition to the binomial distribution, I attempted to solve this using the above formula (approximation) since n is rather large and p is > 0.1.  However, my results between the 2 approaches are not spot on (not the same) (.1452 and .1294)

Comment: A Poisson approximation $\lambda = np = 10/3$ gives you a closer value. $P(5) = e^{-\lambda}\dfrac{\lambda^5}{5!} \approx 0.1223$.

Comment: Thank you Vinay, but I read to use Poisson when p is really small, less than .1. I have to stick with the approximation formula because that's what my exercise is asking for. Does .1452 seem about right to you or did I mess up?

Comment: No, that's the value you'd get. But even the normal approximation is used only when $n$ is large. the Poisson approximation works slightly better here.